# Multiple image requirements

Tags: android, shell

I am finding a way to auto generate android `nine-patch,mipmap and drawable` icons. I have multiple projects which require to repeat the same process frequently. How can I solve this ?

I was using android studio before but now I am using script and basic commands to auto generate the image in basic format for `ninepatch`.
Any suggestions are appreciated

## To generate a nine-patch for android

```
magick mogrify default.png -bordercolor transparent -border 0.5 -format png *.png
mv -v default.png default.9.png
```

## resize and generate image

```
convert default.png -background none -resize 24x24\! $drawable/*.png
```